# Regex - matching brazilian phone numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use Regex to validate brazilian phone numbers.

For some reason, I cannot use \b to indicate the beginning and the end for the match. In this case, my Regex selects some invalid phone numbers as valid.

RegEX:

```
\(?([0-9]{2,3}|0{1}((x|[0-9]){2,3}[0-9]{2}))\)?\s*[0-9]{4,5}[- ]*[0-9]{4}
```

Valid numbers:

```
(00)0000-0000; true
(00)000000000; true 
(00) 00000 0000; true
00 00000 0000; true
(000)00000 0000; true
```

Invalid numbers:

```
23232443243243423432; true
(0000)000000000; true
a00 00000-0000 ; true
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you match the whole string by enclosing the whole regex with `^` and `$`, will it be OK?

Comment: Parentheses, spaces and dashes don't actually mean anything as far as telephone devices are concerned, you could very well strip those from the string before validating.

Comment: @Havenard, I'm using this Regex as Watson Assistant pattern. That's the problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not working :(

Comment: Try `\(?(\b[0-9]{2,3}|0((x|[0-9]){2,3}[0-9]{2}))\)?\s*[0-9]{4,5}[- ]*[0-9]{4}\b`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lHbA3X/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great! You can answer the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place word boundaries at the "right" places. They must placed at the first obligatory word char matching pattern and after the last obligatory word char.

```
\(?\b([0-9]{2,3}|0((x|[0-9]){2,3}[0-9]{2}))\)?\s*[0-9]{4,5}[- ]*[0-9]{4}\b
   ^^                                                                   ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lHbA3X/3)

If you put `\b` before `\(?`, when there is a `(` before a digit, the word boundary will invalidate the match if there is no word char right before the `(`.